Is it possible to return to the Grafted Scion in the beginning of Elden Ring?
In the beginning of Elden Ring, when you leave the Chapel of Anticipation, you’ll find a Grafted Scion boss that you’re meant to die to.
Later, is there any way to come back and kill it (excluding NG+ and all that)? If you do, what happens? And what’s behind the fog gate that it’s guarding?

Yes, you can return and fight the Grafted Scion outside of the Chapel of Anticipation after leaving there early in the game.
In the Liurnia of the Lakes region, in the western portion, there's an area called The Four Belfries. One of them is marked as the "Precipice of Anticipation". Sound familiar?
You can interact with these belfries with an Imbued Sword Key to activate their waygates. The belfry that says "Precipice of Anticipation" will take you back to the Church of Anticipation.
Beating the Grafted Scion in this area grants the same rewards described in this answer, as though you had defeated it at the beginning of the game. In this area, and only when you've returned using the belfry waygate, you will also be able to pick up the Stormhawk King and Stormhawk Deenh.
